# Changing PCIE/ m.2 SSD drive

Tags: hard-drive, ssd, pci-express

I have this following PCIE SSD on my Lenovo Ideapad U530 20289. I would like to replace this SSD with much more capacity, so I could install windows on it.

[image]

I went through few PCIE SSD and I found this following one common as I could not find the same RAMAXEL of higher capacity. Can I replace with this following one ?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing not. The 'old' SSD is a [M.2/NGFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M.2) drive, the new drive is a msata drive(which is an older format). You want another m2 drive. M.2 is a LOT smaller and has a different/incompatible pin out. There's also different varients using sata or pcie I believe, with the same M.2 pinout. You want a M.2 *sata* drive I suspect, rather than a M.2 PCIe drive.

EDIT: The revised drive option *looks* like it should work. I'd note for posterity the *original* question had an msata drive

Comment: So, M.2/NGFF and M.2 are two different things, and I am even too confused with length. If I go through drive of 256 GB, the length of drive is long and I doubt it won't fit.

Comment: They're the same - NGFF is an old name for M.2. The Kingfast drive is msata. The tricky thing is there's sata and pcie M2 drives

Comment: What about length ... Is it like I can't have more than 128 GB because I find drive with more capacity than that are long ...

Comment: I have no idea I'm afraid.

Comment: Can I replace with this ? 

http://ecx.images-amazon.com/images/I/617I9a-PrXL._SL1000_.jpg

Comment: It looks like the right form factor. I'd add the multiple *major* edits make it hard to keep up. Its a bit like moving the goalposts when I got the shot lined up.

Comment: Oh, I am sorry about that.... Anyways, thank you so much... Will try this for sure... And yeah, will keep in mind about goal post next time...